# Rotate an image inside Table-head without increasing the width or the column

Tags: html, css, html-table, rotation, width

Rotate an image by fixing the width of the table head.

**[DEMO](http://cssdeck.com/labs/fx1ppjjg)**

Please look at the demo. The width of the columns should be just around 30px but not reflecting as the image width ( which is rotated ) is a lot more.

Want to have a rotated image and still keep a small width ( The width of the rotated image will fit into the **td** with ease, but unable to make it so)

Tried several methods, unable to get the required result. Any help is appreciated.

Code

```
<div class="bs-example">
<table class="table">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>#</th>
      <th class="rotate"><image src="http://example.com/NKV2Yt" height="20" /></th>
      <th class="rotate"><image src="http://example.com/NKV2Yt" height="20" /></th>
      <th class="rotate"><image src="http://example.com/NKV2Yt" height="20" /></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>M</td>
      <td>O</td>
      <td>@</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>J</td>
      <td>T</td>
      <td>@</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>L</td>
      <td>t</td>
      <td>@</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div><!-- /example -->
```

CSS ==>

```
th{
  height:200px;
  width:30px !important;
}
.rotate{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+ */
 -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* Firefox 3.5-15 */
  -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* IE 9 */
   -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* Opera 10.50-12.00 */
      transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come across this problem before myself. Only solution I found was to wrap the images in another element, give that a relative position and absolute position the image to that element

```
table{
  margin: 20px 0 0 30px;}
tr,td,th{
  border: 1px solid;
}
th{
  height:100px;
  width:30px;
}
.rotate img {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* Chrome, Safari 3.1+ */
     -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* Firefox 3.5-15 */
      -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* IE 9 */
       -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* Opera 10.50-12.00 */
          transform: rotate(-90deg);  /* Firefox 16+, IE 10+, Opera 12.10+ */

}

.rotate span {
  position:relative;
  width:30px;
  height:100px;
  display:block;
}

.rotate span img {
  position: absolute;
  left:-15px;
  top:50px
}
```

The wrap your images in a span

```
<th class="rotate"><span><image src="http://goo.gl/NKV2Yt" height="20" /></span></th>
```

Updated example here http://cssdeck.com/labs/tnbuiyv8

Comment: Thanks, will check and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Try `max-width` for `th`

```
max-width: 30px;
```